# Registrar fecha en español en mysql

Tags: mysql

Estoy tratando de registrar la fecha en español en *MySQL* pero solo la registra en inglés, quisiera saber si se puede registrar la fecha en español.

De antemano gracias.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

así tengo el campo de fecha, y no la guarda en español.

Comment: Por favor lee [ask] y trata de proveer un [mcve]

Comment: ¿Por qué quieres que la base de datos haga un trabajo que le corresponde en todo caso a tu vista que es mostrar una fecha con un formato determinado?

Comment: entonces la fecha siempre se va a registrar en inglés, solo que se va a reflejar en español en la vista?

Comment: Nop. Y no es recomendable que la guardes como `VARCHAR` a menos que nunca vayas a hacer operaciones con esa fecha. Es mejor abrazar el formato estándar `AAAA-MM-DD`, que -por cierto- no es en inglés.

Comment: Las fechas en la BD deben registrarse como fechas, 2021-03-10, es un dato de tipo fecha. Si la guardas con hora, además podrás tener la hora. Al mostrarlas en pantalla, debes realizar la conversión al lenguaje que desees, el default es inglés.

Comment: El formato YYYY-MM-DD no es inglés. Es el formato de fecha internacional (ISO 8601). Y el motivo por el que se escogió como estándar es principalmente porque empieza por los períodos más largos, por lo que se pueden comparar fechas entre sí como si fueran Strings. Los ingleses británicos usan el formato 10-03-1945 (DD-MM-YYYY) y los ingleses americanos utilizan 03-10-1945 (MM-DD-YYYY).

Comment: esta es mi consulta                                                                              $fecha = $_POST['fecha'];                                                                        SELECT DATE_FORMAT('fecha', '%d/%m/%Y'); y no muestra nada.

Comment: Trabajas con PHP ?? cual es el codigo con el que muestras la fecha

Comment: Ponelo en el POST, no en el comentario

Answer (score 0):

Es que efectivamente la fecha en mysql, el formato "date" en mysql es como lo ves. año-mes-dia. Y está bien que sea así, porque si hay que comparar fechas, calcular tiempo de distancia entre una y otra, es mejor que sean todas en el mismo formato universal y se convertirán al que sea necesario.

Dicho eso, en MySQL puedes convertir cualquier fecha al formato que necesites de esta manera:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT('2021-03-10 21:03:00', '%d/%m/%Y');
```

y te devolverá el correspondiente 10/03/2021.
Puedes ver todas las "%opciones" disponibles en https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format

Por otro lado, si no te sientes cómodo con eso, puedes crear una columna timestamp y guardar el tiempo en segundos y luego convertirlo cuando lo necesites mostrar usando esto:

```
SELECT DATE_FORMAT(FROM_UNIXTIME('1234567890'), '%dd/%mm/%yyyy');
```

que te devolverá 13/02/2009

Lo bueno de usar los formatos date y timestamp es que podrás después trabajar con las fechas con las funciones nativas de mysql que te encantarán en el futuro.

Comment: Esta respuesta no aborda el problema del OP, el quiere guardar fechas en español, lo que es un error. El mostrarlas en su código es como debe ser y dudo que eso sea mysql.

Comment: La respuesta explica porqué no es una buena idea guardarlo en español, y explica cómo mostrar el contenido en español. Discutir porqué él no explica bien las cosas no creo que sea ayudar. Y discutir porqué discutir que los que saben no le ayudan, tampoco.

Comment: Si en una respuesta explicas que no es buena idea guardarlos en español, eso es un comentario. Una respuesta se hace para resolver el problema del OP, no para explicarle algo. Para eso están los comentarios donde hay más gente discutiendo.

Comment: @Excorpion Decir que las fechas no se almacenan en formatos distintos por cuestiones de eficiencia en los procesos de comparación es un hecho demostrable empíricamente, no es una opinión. Sea el lenguaje que sea, incluso para un ser humano, para comparar `2021-03-10` con `09/03/2021` es necesario añadir, al menos, un paso al algoritmo, que siempre será una fracción de tiempo superior a 0, por más pequeña que sea